# Setting a default value for a field in a formset in Django

Tags: python, django

In a formset in Django, how do we set a default value for a field which needs a value from the http session? Since a session is required to get the value, we cannot set a default value in the model class itself. And I am not able to understand how to explicitly set the value in each form in the formset before saving in the view function.

Setting the initial attribute in the construction of the FormSet would work but for whatever reason, I get a compilation error. The code is like this:

```
formset = LineItemsInlineFormSet(initial=[{'updated_by':'user'}])
```

The compilation error is: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initial'

I am using Django 1.1.1

Any insight will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How did you define `LineItemsInlineFormSet`? If you've created your own subclass, did you remember to use `**kwargs` in its `__init__`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiom to instance a formset with initial data is:

```
data = {
     'form-TOTAL_FORMS': u'2',
     'form-INITIAL_FORMS': u'0',
     'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': u'',
     'form-0-updated_by': u'user',
     'form-1-updated_by': u'user',
}

formset = LineItemsInlineFormSet(data)
```

#### Update:

As [Jonny Buchanan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6760/insin) noted, this approach gives you a bound formset, which will display validation errors if all required data is not provided. If it is not what you want, create your formset [passing a custom Form with desired settings to `django.forms.formsets.formset_factory()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#formsets).

It is common to set `updated_by` as the current logged-in user [automagically upon update](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#saving-objects-in-the-formset). If this is what you want:

1. omit the `updated_by` field in the form;
2. `save()` with `commit=False` if it is a ModelFormset;
3. set `updated_by` to current user; and
4. save object instances, now with the default `commit=True`.

In the admin site there is a convenient way to do this with inlines: overrride [ModelAdmin.save_formset](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_formset).

Comment: This approach gives you a bound formset, which will display validation errors if all required data is not provided.